# Automatically configure Opscenter to manage an existing Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes, opscenter

I'm using Opscenter to manage my Cassandra cluster. Opscenter is started after my Cassandra cluster is already running. When opening Opscenter on my browser at port 8888 I have to manually give the Cassandra master's IP.

Due to my deployment (Kubernetes and Docker) it's a schlep to get the IP of the Cassandra master. Is there a config I can edit to automatically connect to the master at startup? I am able to find the master IP using a bash command - I just want to specify it in a config file.

Comment: Did you check seed_hosts in https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.1/opsc/configure/opscConnectionConfig_r.html?scroll=opscConnectionConfig__clusternameconf_unique_4

Comment: FYI- There is no a such thing as a "Cassandra master."  Cassandra uses a peer-to-peer architecture.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try, is to provide OpsCenter with a configuration file for your cluster.  If you installed OpsCenter in `/etc`, that file should be in the `/etc/opscenter/clusters` directory, and it's filename should match the name of your cluster (with underscores for special characters and spaces).  The contents of that file should look something like this:

```
$ cat clusters/DEV_LOAD_TEST.conf
[jmx]
username = 
password = 
port = 7199

[kerberos_client_principals]

[kerberos]

[agents]

[kerberos_hostnames]

[kerberos_services]

[cassandra]
username = devadmin
seed_hosts = 10.0.0.4, 10.0.0.9, 10.0.0.6
api_port = 9160
password = reindeerflotilla
```

See Dennis' link above for more detailed config information.  Note, that link is for OpsCenter 5.1, so be sure to double-check your version when looking up DataStax documentation.